# Possion?? What is the probability that at least 2 custumers show up during Happy hour??

Tags: probability

A certain bar noticed during its  Happy Hour morning on Average 5 bar patrons come by for a drink before work. Let $X$ be  the number of custumers
that arrive during the morning Happy Hour.

what type of distribution does $X$ follow??

What is the probability that at least 2 custumers show up during Happy hour??

---

The distribution is Possion

$$f(x) = \frac{\lambda^x}{x!} e^{-\lambda} $$

$\lambda = \frac{1}{2}$

**Not sure how to find by hand. Using R**

> ppois(2,1/2)

[1] 0.9856123

Using Ti 89 titatinum  has Possion Cdf where can enter lamba,lower , upper limet put in  1/2,0,2 and gave the same number.

Comment: keep downvoting me to 0. I dont care. I care more about how I score on final

Comment: Why is lambda equal to 0.5?

Comment: thats how I am programmed. Is it 2??

Comment: Explain me (us) please why do you think lambda is equal to 0.5

Answer (score 0):

The probability that at least two customers show up is $1$ minus the probability that the number of customers is either $0$ or $1.$